# Is it possible to change the number format in the R Environment?

Tags: r, formatting, scale

I've recently been working with large data sets and was wondering if it was possible to change the number format of the observation in the R environment.

The numbers have the current format: `13292276`

Is there an R function for displaying large numbers separated by commas?

So the output would be: `13,292,276`

Comment: If you're talking about general printing in the console, no not really. There are built-in options to prefer scientific notation or to limit significant digits, but not for adding "big marks" like commas. In any particular result context, however, (e.g., making tables, labels in graphs, etc.) there are lots of formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scales()` package

```
library(scales)    
label_comma()(13292276)

[1] "13,292,276"
```